facebook API for getting all type of post in my feed
I am trying to get all types of post's visible on my feed of all the user's, is their any way to do it.
I tried differnt facebook graph api but they are only retruning me posts made by me.
I have read on multiple post that you can only get the post those are made by you.
I just want all the public post data of my facebook wall


I just want all the public post data of my facebook wall

That is not possible. Facebook does not provide any API, to get the same posts a user would see in their feed.

if  it is not possible then how ad search platform shows different ads and engagements on them because they also don't have access to all the profiles

Are you referring to Facebook's own Ad Library? Well that is Facebook's own product, of course that has access to all the data they want it to have access to. But that doesn't mean that they are willing to expose that same data to you via API, for completely different purposes.

No other platform like ad-search tools like minea shows all the users posted ads and engagement but the Facebook ad library doesn't give you all the insights of an ad of other users unless you have permission from that user. So my question is how these platforms are able to show such info.

I don't know that tool; but if you encounter services offering data that can't be obtained via the official 3rd-party developer APIs, then usually it is either a case where a Facebook partner has special access, or - scraping.
